# Zoom image in HTML and print

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, zooming

I have a requirement to print a zoomed portion of image container. we have written js and css to zoom a image inside a container.

Initially :

```
<img src="../img.gif" style="width:200px;height:200px"/>
```

After zooming:

```
<img src="../img.gif" style="left: -129.86px; top: -203.33px; width: 1090.8px; height: 1055.7px; -ms-user-select: auto;"/>
```

In the browser view it works perfectly [i am hiding the other portion of the image ]

But while printing the HTML with the applied new styles, its not printing the proper zoomed portion. Please let me know how to crop the zoomed portion only in the printing.

Thanks
Jeevitha

Comment: could you please provide a sample on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: show your printing code